# using php to call bash script with user prompts (ubuntu 20, bash cli, php 7.4)

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

After a couple of days searching message boards and suggestions from ChatGPT, I got something which does this correctly for most commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
function OpenCLI(){
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
     );
     $process = proc_open("/bin/bash", $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null, array('tty'=>true));//'tty'=>true so that pseudo-terminal is used so can talk to ssh command
     stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
     stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
     stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
     return array("process" => $process, "pipes" => $pipes);
}
function CLIExists($cli){
    return is_resource($cli["process"]);
}
function CLIWrite($cli,$text){
    fwrite($cli["pipes"][0], $text); 
}
function CLIRead($cli,$max_ms=100, $max_len=10000){
    $ms=0;
    $str="";
    while(true){
        $new=fread($cli["pipes"][1], 1024);     
        if(strlen($new)>0){
            $str.=$new;
            //print "new: '" . $new . "'";
            $ms=0;
        }
        else{
            $ms++;
            //print "ms: '" . $ms . "'";
        }
        if($ms>$max_ms || strlen($str)>$max_len)
            break;
        usleep(1000);
    }    
    return $str;
}
```

However, any attempts to use the "ssh" command (which requires a password prompt) causes it to stop being able to send text to or receive text from the bash instance it opened up. Instead, the output of the command bypasses the php script completely and prints directly to the console.

Example with ssh:

```
$cli=OpenCLI();
if(CLIExists($cli)){
    CLIWrite($cli,"ssh admin@10.10.74.22\n");
    $res1=CLIRead($cli);
    CLIWrite($cli,"[password]\n");
    $res2=CLIRead($cli);
    print "res1: '$res1'\n";
    print "res2: '$res2'\n";
}
```

output to the console:

```
res1: ''
res2: ''

admin@10.10.74.22's password: /dustin# 
admin@10.10.74.22's password: 
admin@10.10.74.22's password:
```

I was originally planning on using SH2.php but during tests it failed at random and I'm not looking forward to debugging a library that took me days to get working in the first place.

In addition to being able to automate updating of remote devices I also want to create something that will allow me to easily automate any process that I can do manually by typing in commands. I would be just as happy if someone knows of a set of functions that does this in python (haven't tried yet) or nodejs (tried and gave up after a week).

Comment: Not a solution for what is asked, but why do you still use passwords in combination with ssh? Or is that the password of the private key used to connect?

Comment: In this case it is because I have a constantly updating list of over 1000 devices in the field which have to be occasionally logged into via a variety of computers and cell phones.

Comment: Which is not a reason to prefer passwords over keys, in contrary. But I absolutely agree that you know your situation and I don't. I just asked because of you use a key you might want to use an empty password. Which means you do _not_ have to enter a password at all. If you are in possession of the private key.

Comment: To clarify, none of the devices in the field have private keys listed in our database. If I set them up to require keys to log in for basic troubleshooting,  I'd have to write and maintain key management apps in at least 4 different operating systems in order for everyone to have access when they need it. Also, I still need to write code to log into all of the existing devices with passwords in order to initialize the key entries in the database (which will be used when VPN access is necessary).

Comment: But you need to do exactly the same to set the password/create the account anyway. Note: you use the same key for all devices, since you use the same user account for all of them (I assume). You place the _public_ key on the device (that can be automated during setup) and keep the _secret_ key at the system which has to perform the automated login you are trying to implement.

Comment: I still don't want to manually upload the key to all of them but I suppose that would be fine in the long term for devices that don't need unique passwords, and then I would just have to manually install the key on a bunch of cell phones and laptops once. I also still want to figure out how to directly communicate with a cli though for other cases.

Comment: Sure, I probably fail to understand your setup process by which you create the accounts in the first place which you then want to use here in your ssh connection attempt. I though that since you have to create those accounts anyway it should be trivial to also install the public key once you are on it. That probably is where I am wrong. My otivation only was easy the usage of ssh on CLI since you would not have to specify and password at connection time then. Which appears to be your current issue.

Comment: My current issue is that there are no known keys on the devices already in the field and all I have is a list of usernames/passwords.  Though I agree that going forward that would work. Also, I previously assumed that using the same private key for multiple devices would make ssh give the "unknown device fingerprint"  error.